# Trying to understand how to store current url for redirecting to after authentication

Tags: angular

I have a somewhat complicated routing structure with lazy loading that looks something like this:

```
// app-routing.module.ts

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    canMatch: [MyAuthGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/main.module').then(m => m.MainModule),
  }
  ...
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
  ],
  providers: [],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

```
// main.module.ts

@NgModule({
  imports: [MainRoutingModule],
})
export class MainModule {}
```

```
// main-routing.module.ts

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'somewhere',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./somewhere/somewhere.module').then(m => m.SomewhereModule),
  },
  ...
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [MainModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [MainModule],
})
export class MainRoutingModule {}
```

So from my understanding of the routing documentation, `CanMatch` is what should be used to determine whether files should get loaded for a lazy loaded route...  But the `CanMatch` function is called with two arguments: `route: Route, segments: UrlSegment[]` neither of these arguments contain the full url of where the user was attempting to go to..  So if a user tries to go to `/some/where/over/here/123?x=123&y=456` I would want to be doing:

```
 canMatch(route: Route, segments: UrlSegment[]): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
  if (!this.authService.authenticated) {
    this.authService.currentURL = // ?????????? where do I get the entire url the user is attempting to go to including query params?
    this.router.navigate(['sign-in']);
  } else {
    return true;
  }
```

It appears the `CanActivate` function has `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` which has a URL property, but that guard is not for lazy loading... So I am super confused..............  How is this supposed to be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can inject router into your guard and use `this.router.getCurrentNavigation();`

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jnahtj?file=src/can-match-test.ts (url printed to console)

```js
@Injectable()
export class CanMatchTest implements CanMatch {
  constructor(private router: Router) { }
  canMatch(route: Route, segments: UrlSegment[]) {
    const navigation = this.router.getCurrentNavigation();
    let url = '/';
    if (navigation) {
      url = navigation.extractedUrl.toString();
    }
    console.log(url);
    return true;
  }
}
```

Please refer to the issue link
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17359#issuecomment-584776004